# Intercept outgoing HXR requests and their content

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am looking to monitor all outgoing HXR requests on the page in order to intercept a specific one that I wish to extract its data to log.

Here's the specific request I am trying to intercept:

[Request header from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWnmu.png)

[Request body I want to extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuSaL.png)

Here's what I tried so far:

```
(function(send) {
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(body) {
    var info="send data\r\n"+body;
    console.log(info);
    send.call(this, body);
};
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

This seems to be somehow working because I get some requests logged in the console but not the ones I am looking for.
I also get some  `send data [object FormData]` logged.

I am probably missing something about which HXR requests I am intercepting with my script and would love some help!
Thanks for your time!

Comment: You'll need to show us the code that makes the requests that you cannot intercept.

Answer (score 0):

This may just be the reason for the implicit conversion, you can try the `JSON.Stringify(body)` method.